# Sonata User - Customize admin query with security

Tags: security, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have extended SonataUserBundle and I'd like to customize the Admin query to restrict the list:

```php
class UserAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin
{
// ...
    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $query = parent::createQuery($context);
        $query->andWhere( 
            $query->expr()->eq($query->getRootAlias().'.company', ':comp')
        );
        $query->setParameter('comp', $securityContext->user->getCompany());
        return $query;
    }
// ...
}
```

Here, I'm trying to make the user only see users from his company.
But `$securityContext` is not set.

Can someone tell how to inject the security context into my admin class ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to inject the security context service in your UserAdmin service.

In order to do that, you have to update the services.yml of your bundle:

```
services:
    # ...
    sonata.admin.user:
        class: My\ProjectBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
        tags:
            - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: users, label: users}
        arguments:
            - null
            - Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
            - SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            - @security.context #forth argument
        calls:
            - [setTranslationDomain, [MyProjectBundle]]
            - [setUserManager, [@fos_user.user_manager]]
```

In you UserAdmin class, override the constructor:

```
namespace My\ProjectBundle\Admin;

class UserAdmin extends Admin
{

    private $securityContext = null;

    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, $secutiryContext=null)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $query = parent::createQuery($context);
        $query->andWhere( 
            $query->expr()->eq($query->getRootAlias().'.company', ':comp')
        );
        $query->setParameter('comp', $this->securityContext->user->getCompany());
        return $query;
    }
}
```

I didn't test this code, but i use this method to inject service_container in sonata admin to manage file upload using Gedmo Uploadable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok I see, but I don't have any service defined in my bundle. If I put one, it does not get interpreted.

Comment: Well, it's because you have to had a call to the setUserManager method in your service definition. See vendor/sonata-project/user-bundle/Sonata/UserBundle/Resurces/config/admin_orm.xml

Comment: Yeah I deleted my 2nd comment. So about my first one, do you have a clue ?

Comment: You have to load your config.yml using the dependency injection.

Check the file My\ProjectBundle\DependencyInjection\MyProjectExtension

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#using-the-load-method

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but what about;

```
$user = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

first thing in `public function createQuery($context = 'list') {`

and then at `setParameter` you can just use `$user->getCompany()`

Like this;

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $user = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->andWhere( 
        $query->expr()->eq($query->getRootAlias().'.company', ':comp')
    );
    $query->setParameter('comp', $user->getCompany());
    return $query;
}
```